# Customizing JWT generation not working in WSO2 APIM 4.0.0

Tags: java, jwt, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I tried to implement the steps given in WSO2 4.0.0 documentation https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.0.0/deploy-and-publish/deploy-on-gateway/api-gateway/passing-enduser-attributes-to-the-backend-via-api-gateway/ for customizing JWT Claims.

As given in the documentation, I created the custom JWT generator java class, generated the jar and placed it under WSO2 Home/repository/components/lib folder . Did the necessary configurations in deployment.toml for enabling JWT and restarted the server.

Need suggestions on this as i have followed the steps given in the documentation.

I execute the examples `CustomGatewayJWTGenerator,CustomJWTGenerator` of [repo](https://github.com/wso2/samples-apim) official examples.

```
{
  "sub": "xxxx",
  "aut": "xxxx",
  "aud": "xxx",
  "nbf": xxx,
  "azp": "xxx",
  "scope": "xxx",
  "iss": "xx://xxx:9443/oauth2/token",
  "exp": xxxxx,
  "iat": xxxxx,
  "jti": "xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxx"
  //custom
   "name:"xxxxx",
    "lastname":"xxxx"
}
```

[deployment.toml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXoCw.png)

[api-manager.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TF0Rw.png)

[repository\components\dropins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7rWM.png)

[repository\components\lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYUBv.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can customize JWT by adding custom claims using a `CustomGatewayJWTGenerator` as in [docs](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.0.0/deploy-and-publish/deploy-on-gateway/api-gateway/passing-enduser-attributes-to-the-backend-via-api-gateway/#jwt-self-contained-access-tokens). Follow the steps below to test this.

1. Get this [sample code](https://github.com/wso2/samples-apim/tree/master/CustomGatewayJWTGenerator) and modify the `CustomGatewayJWTGenerator.populateStandardClaims()` class as below.

```java
@Override
public Map<String, Object> populateStandardClaims(JWTInfoDto jwtInfoDto) {
    Map<String, Object> claims = super.populateStandardClaims(jwtInfoDto);
    claims.put("custom-attribute", "123");
    return claims;
}
```

2. Run `mvn clean install` and generate the jar file.
3. Copy `CustomGatewayJWTGenerator-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` to `<APIM_HOME>/repository/components/dropins` directory.
4. Add following config to the `<APIM_HOME>/repository/conf/deployment.toml`.

```ini
[apim.jwt]
enable = true

[apim.jwt.gateway_generator]
impl = "org.wso2.carbon.test.CustomGatewayJWTGenerator"
```

5. Start/Restart the server.
6. Create and publish a sample REST API in Publisher.
7. Subscribe and invoke the created API in Devportal.
8. You can see that the custom attribute is passed to the backend by decoding the JWT.

```
{
  ...

  "custom-attribute": "123",

  ...
}
```

Comment: I have downloaded the API 4.0.0 again. and I've downloaded the sample code, and performed the suggested steps, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Did you try enabling default `CustomJWTGenerator` using apim.jwt.enable = true in deployment.toml? It should display default attributes.

Comment: yes, I have enabled it with [apim.jwt]
enable = true and the java class [apim.jwt.gateway_generator]
impl = "org.wso2.carbon.test.CustomGatewayJWTGenerator". I have edited the question with a screenshot of the deployment.toml

Comment: Note that `CustomGatewayJWTGenerator-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` should be placed on `dropins` directory. According to your description you have copied it into `libs` directory. Can you also check that?

Comment: I have checked and it is in the "dropins" folder. I have edited the question with the screenshot.